# What is the difference between dachdecker and dachdeckern?

Tags: grammatical-number

I wonder what the difference between *dachdecker* and *dachdeckern* is. As I understand, both cases are plural. Am I right?

Comment: Der Dachdecker (Nom. Sing.) gibt den anderen Dachdeckern (Dat. Plur.) ein Bier. Die Dachdecker (Nom. Plur.) danken dem  Dachdecker (Dat. Sing.) mit einem herzlichen "Vergelt's Gott!" Noch lange ist daraufhin der Dachdecker (Gen. Plur.) fröhliches Gespräch zu hören, denn des Dachdeckers (Gen. Sing.) Bier tut seine Wirkung.

Comment: They are different cases. See the table in the "Grammatik"-section of [the duden entry for Dachdecker](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dachdecker) for details.

Comment: German has grammatical cases (there are four cases in German). Learn what cases are, and how to use them! They are very fundamental in German language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are four cases, which are nominative, accusative, dative and genitive, in German language.

In case, there is **only one** roofer.

Nominative case

> Ich bin ein **Dachdecker** = I am a roofer.

Accusative case

> Ich denke an meinen Dachdecker = I think of my roofer (I dont know why :)

Dative case

> Ich sagte meinem Dachdecker = I told my roofer.

Genitive case

> Das ist der Hut meines Dachdeckers = This is my roofer´s hat.

---

Lets say, there are **more than one** roofer.

Nominative case

> Wir sind Dachdecker = We are roofers.

Accusative case

> Ich denke an meine Dachdecker = I think of my roofers.

Dative case

> Ich sagte meinen **Dachdeckern** = I told my roofers.

Genitive case

> ⁠⁠⁠Das sind die Hüte meiner Dachdecker = These are the hats of my roofers.

Briefly, `Dachdecker` is roofer and the plural form of it is also `Dachdecker`. However, if you want to use the plural form of this word in the dative case, it "magically" becomes `Dachdeckern`. Dont ask me why, this is the German language :)

and please look also at the comments, there are some important complementary info there.

Comment: "Dont ask me why" - you explained why: "There are four cases in German language."

Comment: It may be worth noting that "Dachdecker" shares this declination scheme with many other nouns ending with -er: Förster, Metzger, Bäcker etc. But alas, not all masculine Nouns ending with -er are declined in this way. For example, the nominative plural of "Bauer" (farmer) is not "die Bauer" but "die Bauern". (Otherwise German would be much too easy!)

Comment: 1. »*Dont ask me why*« is not what people expects to read in an answer. 2. There is nothing *magic* in German. There are rules: The noun »Dachdecker« belongs to the S6-declination group. This means: It always has the same ending, which can be *-el* or *-er*, except in genitive singular (*-els* or *-ers*) and dativ plural (*-eln* or *-ern*). Other S6-words: Ending in *-er*: *Bürger, Jäger, Opfer, Feuer, Meister, Gegner, ...*. Ending in *-el*: *Rudel, Teufel, Segel, Artikel*. Words in this group are always masculine or neuter. *(to be continued)* ...

Comment: ... To this group belong many designations of offenders (*Mörder*, *Einbrecher*), almost all names of professions (*Bäcker, Schuster, Tischler*) and almost all designations of residents (*Wiener, Österreicher, Europäer*)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I have tried to answer, what OP was looking for. I did not want to burden the OP with lots of grammar rules and wanted to state it humorously. However, in any case, the your and other comments are improving the quality of answer.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast When it comes to the rules, What Mark Twain said about the rules in the German language is noteworthy: *There are more exceptions to the rule than instances of it*